# iOS / MonoTouch equivalent of Windows Forms show/hide dialogs?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ios, xamarin.ios

Getting lost in how things are "supposed" to be done in iOS. A couple basic questions...

In normal .NET we can create forms (views) and raise them as dialogs through ShowDialog() which returns a value, etc. I want to accomplish the same idea with iOS using MonoTouch.

- Is `this.Add(myNewView);` the correct way to show a view on top of the current view (like a dialog?)
- How do you close it once the work has been done? (.NET equivalent of `this.Close();`)?

Comment: Not sure if this helps http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Feb-23.html.  More examples here that might help https://github.com/migueldeicaza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most similar thing to .NET ShowDialog(), is to present modal view controllers.

To do this, call the PresentModalViewController method of the parent controller that will display the view:

```
this.PresentModalViewController(myModalController, true);
```

To hide/dismiss it, call the DismissModalViewControllerAnimated method on the controller that is displayed:

```
myModalController.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true);
```

The boolean parameters indicate whether you want to animate the presentation/dismissal.